# win forms hangs at ShowDialog on windows7

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

My app hangs at show dialog where im getting parameter for query but only on windows 7. I tried adding (this) but the window opis is stuck behind my main window and cant do nothing. Please help

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        opis opi = new opis();
        opi.ShowDialog(this);
        string sqlopis = opi.textBox9.Text;


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Rok2016 (Firma, Czas, Dzien, Opis, Kto) VALUES ('" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + comboBox3.Text + "', '" + monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString() + "', @Title, @Kto) ", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", sqlopis);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Kto", label3.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        SqlDataAdapter asdf;
        DataTable ss;
        asdf = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Firma, Czas, Opis,ID FROM Rok2016 WHERE Dzien=@DT AND Kto=@Kto", con);
        asdf.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT", monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString());
        asdf.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kto", label3.Text);
        ss = new DataTable();

        asdf.Fill(ss);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ss;


    }
```

Comment: most probably your SQL query is taking too long and hanging it. Have you tried stepping through or logging some information?

Comment: His sql query isnt taking too long, ShowDialog stops the code until the dialog is closed so it never gets to the query

Comment: Does your main window happen to be TopMost = true? (eg. on top of everything)

Comment: EpicKip TopMost is false. Its not problem with query because it works after I kill dialog from task manager.

Comment: I figured out that dialog appears but is invisible. I see cousor changing and i can click button blindly